# Использование STL и фреймворков в C++

Tags: c++, boost

C++ 2 главные библотеки (ИМХО): одна стандартная, одна почти стандартная([Boost](http://boost.org)). Но ни одна из них не позволяет создавать GUI (с кнопочками, менюшками и т.д.). А потому, есть и фреймворки: `Qt`, `wxWidgets` (MFC не в счет -- он не кроссплатформенен), однако, оба "переписывают" (дублируют) `Stl` (`QString`, `wxString` и т.д.**; **вариант: компилировать `wxWidgets` с использованием `stl` сами разработчики считают не совсем кошерным, т.к. он, по умолчанию, не работает).

Однако, в более-менее большом приложении обязательно будут сторонние библиотеки, которые используют `Stl`, да и не обязательно все классы из `Stl` присутствуют в фреймворке.

Вопросы: что делать с огромным количеством абсолютно бесполезно продублированного кода? Использовать `stl` классы или классы, предоставляемые фреймворком?

**UPD:** Что делать с принципом *DRY* (Don't Repeat Yourself) или это исключение?

**UPD2:** Как я понял, классы Qt серьёзно отличаются от аналогов в stl, а значит и DRY страдает не сильно. Что про wxWidgets? В wxBook написано:

> Классы из wx на 70% похожи на классы из
>   Stl

Я думаю, даже больше. А что с ними и `DRY`?

Comment: А меня вот интересует, по какой причине разработчики Qt реализовали свои контейнеры, вместо того, чтобы использовать стандартные?

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @dzhioev я Qt не использовал и, честно, не знаю. Я думаю, 2 варианта:
1.Не хватило фунцкционала stl(не очень правдоподобно).


2.Не хотели "зависеть" от stl(может надо задать какое-то особое поведение вектора, тоже не очень правдоподобно).

И третий вариант, применившийся в wxWidgets: фреймворк появился до появления stl, и, соответсвенно, классы были реализованы несколько иначе, чем stl

Comment: За все Qt-контейнеры не скажу, но QString на порядок круче, мощнее и удобнее, чем std::string. К тому же имеет средства для конвертации в std::string и обратно.

Comment: @mikillskegg проблему, конечно, проблемой назвать нельзя, это, скорее, неудобство: дублируется код и немного возрастает времякомпиляции, увеличивается размер результирующего файла(например, на MinGW очень значительно)

Comment: Думаю, дело в том, что Qt позиционируется как самодостаточное средство на практически все случаи жизни. Или, во всяком случае, на большинство стандартных случаев. Чтобы с ее помощью можно было написать практически любую программу (кроме очень специальных), к тому же кроссплатформенную. А в принципе я использовал в программе с Qt некоторые библиотеки из boost и проблем совместимости у меня не возникало.

Comment: @mikillskegg я использовал с wxWidgets Boost::Spirit и, естественно, проблем со совместмостью не вознкило. Вопрос в другом: что делать с продублированным кодом? Или это неизбежное зло?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Boost использует stl. Вопрос уже хочется поставить так: а можно ли как-нибудь сократить количество продублированного кода? Например, я думаю, std::vector и QVector очень похожи.

p.s. В Boost есть limits, который создан, чтобы продублировать stl, там, где этого файла нет, но это не в счет))

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов, ответьте мне на вопрос: а всегда ли можно вместо `std::vector` использовать `QVector`? Имею, в виду, например, в сложносочиненных конструкциях из сторонних хидеров.

Comment: > Что делать с принципом DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) или это исключение

Давайте еще вспомним, что в MFC есть CString (аналог std::string, но гораздо более функциональный), CArray (что-то типа vector'а), CList и т.д.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Лично мое мнение - *вопрос надуманный,* поскольку концепция `DRY` (особенно в отношении контейнеров) намного в меньшей степени применима к устоявшимся фреймворкам, которые пережили несколько мажорных версий.

> - Тем более, что, например, если говорить о `STL, Qt и Boost`, то `DRY`, за исключением некоторых моментов, не нарушается.
> - Все `Qt` поддерживают семантику `copy-on-write`, а иногда вообще не совпадают с контейнерами `STL` в плане соответствия названия и назначения *(например, `std::set` и `QSet` - это совершенно разные вещи).*
> - `boost-specific` контейнеры нигде не дублируют функциональность, предоставляемую `STL`.

- На уровне таких проектов решение о реализации своего набора контейнеров может быть принято чуть ли не исходя из аргументов типа *`"std::vector` плохо смотрится в коде вместе с `QString"`.*

> Или, например, если вы подойдете и спросите у девелоперов [`EASTL`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html), слышали ли они про `DRY` и способы уменьшения энтропии в системы, то, мне кажется, вам рассмеются в лицо :)

- *Количество продублированного кода,* как вы это называете, не является проблемой до тех пор, пока под кодом подразумевается код фреймворка.

> - Для своих проектов полезно выбрать некоторую **стратегию использования контейнеров,** например, используем только `QXyz` или `std::xyz`.
> - Причем понятно, что под *использованием* здесь имеется ввиду использование в интерфейсах. На уровне реализаций конкретных интерфейсов можете использовать что угодно и как угодно, хоть `std::vector,` написанный на ассемблере. Но протаскивать его вверх по иерархии, естественно, не стоит - достаточно в местах, где контейнер является частью интерфейса, осуществить соответствующее преобразование.

- Аргумент про размер выходного файла и время компиляции, тоже, на мой взгляд, несколько оторван от реальности.

> По своему опыту скажу, что приложение с [`boost::graph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) замечательно работает под `ARM`, а подключение любого хэдера [`boost::mpl`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) сравнимо с подключением всех контейнеров `Qt` в плане времени компиляции.

- На практике, лично с моей точки зрения, `90%` промышленных продуктов можно построить, если использовать `Qt` *(фреймворк вообще и пользуясь только их контейнерами),* `boost::type_traits` и `<algorithm>`.

> При необходимости также можно `strip'ать` и добавлять в проект какие-либо части `boost` типа [`boost::graph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), [`boost::flyweight`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/index.html) или [`boost::heap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/heap.html).

Comment: Т.е. вывод такой.

1. Если Qt не нужен -> используем стандартные контейнеры std::vector, list, set и пр.
2. Если Qt нужен -> используем qtщные контейнеры, т.к. они круче и код получается однообразнее :-)
3. Если требуется запилить свое выделение памяти или что-либо еще, то ???

Comment: @gecube ... то пилим свое выделение памяти или что-либо еще :)

Comment: Отличную ссыль нашел про сравнение [QTL vs STL][1]

 [1]:http://blog.codeimproved.net/2009/12/qtl-or-stl/

Comment: boost::intrusive boost::pointer container контейнеры boost::interprocess и в особенности boost::container конечно никак не дублируют функциональность ни stl ни друг друга.

интересно взглянуть, каким образом можно умудрится не смешивать те же строки(или контейнеры), например, в проектах завязанных на кучку библиотек с собственной реализацией оных в каждой.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, вообще то, `boost` и `stl` - это статик либы. Так что если Вы не будете из них ничего использовать, и добавляться к получаемому файлу из них не будет. А если вы будете использовать какой то элемент из буста, к примеру, то к вам добавится он и всё что ему требуется для функционирования, но всё остальное - нет.

Comment: - Статик либы - это очень интересное понятие.

- `ARM'овые` и прочие тулчейны такого типа ввиду некоторых особенностей реализации достаточно погано `strip'ают` неиспользуемые символы. Да и вообще говоря, правильно построить `call graph` для символов в произвольном случае - та еще задачка.

Comment: boost и stl это вообще библиотеки по большей части шаблонов. Т.е. вполне логично, что они инстанцируются на каждый случай использования. И поэтому код пухнет, пухнет и пухнет. С Qt прикол такой, что его можно и как библиотеку со статической компоновкой использовать, так и с динамической, но шаблоны оттуда тоже будут все равно вшиты в исполняемый код программы.